# Meaning of というか and 手伝って in this sentence

Tags: meaning

The sentence is from Dragon ball, Mutenrôshi, the teacher of Gokû and Krilin, is telling someone about how good his pupils became. He then says this :

> とくに悟空はもともとの野生**というか**天性の強さも**てつだって**信じられんようなパワーを秘めておる。

I believe てつだって means something along the lines of "in addition", therefore I believe the second part of the sentence means :

> In addition to his natural strength, he is hiding an incredible power.

Am i right so far?

Regarding というか, I found that it means something like "in other words", "or rather"... the idea behind being rephrasing what has been said in another/a better/a more accurate manner. Doesn't seem to fit here though...

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The phrase *[noun]も手伝って【てつだって】* *(lit. with [noun] helping too; with the help of [noun])* is used to cite the *[noun]* as one of the factors contributing to a particular situation. In the present sentence, "*thanks (partly) to*" might be a more apt translation.

As for *というか*, it's indeed true that it indicates the rephrasing of the preceding word/phrase, and this meaning applies fine enough here too.

> (Especially in the case of Goku,) thanks (partly) to his fundamental wild - or should I say innate - strength, Goku has an incredible power hidden within.

Comment: Hi, great answer, thanks :) In the manga, it's definitely 野生, not 野性 though...

Comment: So, the meaning is "his wild, primal, or should I say natural strength" right?
Without the rephrasing, the would the phrase be "もともとの野生の強さも...”? With もともと modifying 強さ and not 野生.

Comment: Looking at it again, I'm now pretty sure 野生の強さ(wild strength) works too. I'll take back what I said about it and edit out that part. I'm sorry I misled you!

Without the rephrasing, I'd say もともとの would modify the entire phrase 野生の強さ (of which fact my translation failed to show).

Answer (score 0):

"Especially Gokuu's original wild...how should I say... nature's strength is helped by a method of hiding his belief in power".

Corrections? I can't comment to add suggestions to the post.